# Jquery Mobile - MVC call dialog box

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-mobile

I have the following code. What I am doing is to show data and then I have a delete button.
 I cannot get the jquery dialog box to come up. I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

```
    @model data_Input

    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>



    <div data-role="page" data-theme="b">
     <div id="main" data-role="content">   

      <div style = "padding-bottom: 10px; padding-top: 20px" class="editor-label">
         @Html.Label("Type"):  @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.data_Name) 
      </div>

      <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.Label("Value"): @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Date) 
      </div>

      <p>

        <a href="#dialog" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-rel="dialog" data-transition="pop">Open dialog</a>
      </p>
   </div>
  </div>


     <!-- Start of second page -->
    <div data-role="page" id="dialog">
     <div data-role="header">
      <h1>
        Bar
      </h1>
    </div><!-- /header -->
    <div data-role="content">
     <p>
        I'm second in the source order so I'm not shown as the page initally.
     </p>
     <p>
        <a href="#foo">Back to foo</a>
     </p>
    </div><!-- /content -->
    <div data-role="footer">
    <h4>
        Page Footer
    </h4>
</div><!-- /footer -->
```

Comment: Are you opening this page directly, or navigating there from another page?  If the latter, are you navigating via ajax?  (if so, your second "page" (the dialog) is never seen by jqm)

Comment: I am on the same page. What I need is a way to confirm that the user wants to delete the records. As such, I have the dialog box on the same .cshtml page

Comment: If you're placing dialog inside `data-role=page`, it won't worry. It should be outside i.e. `body` is direct parent.